# Need to replace DevExpress Bootstrap for ASP.NET Core in project. Solution from experience? Rewrite with different framework like Vue? Smthn else?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, angular, devexpress, devextreme

We need to get rid of DevExpress Bootstrap Controls for ASP.NET Core from project.
What would be the easiest/cheapest/feastet solution?
To simply rewrite everything with a different framework like Angular/Vue/React?
Maybe there is a known framework/method of migrating to DevExpress ASP.NET Core Controls? Or to something else?

Comment: How many controls were used from DevExpress? If you only used a few controls, then you only need a few replacements.  I would not call purchase of some controls from DevExpress a whole "framework", but that of only purchasing some controls to use with your project.  So, does the project use 3-5 or 50 of those DevExpress controls? If you only used a few, then you want to determine what the controls used did, and then what replacements? Their grid controls are VERY nice.   So, you need to find some control replacements, but how many did the project use will quite much determine scope here

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Further clarifications here: (1) We have DevExpress ASP.NET Bootstrap in one of our projects. (2) Unfortunately, DevExpress ASP.NET Bootstrap is in maintenance mode and does not support .NET Core 6.0. We are tied down with .NET Core 2.0.(supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t689475/…) (3) We need to be able to update to .NET Core 6.0. (4) We are are currently investigating the best way to eliminate the DevExpress ASP.NET Bootstrap library from our project in order to not be tied down to .NET Core 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many controls were used from DevExpress?

If you only used a few controls, then you only need a few replacements.

I would not call purchase of some controls from DevExpress a whole "framework", but that of only purchasing some controls to use with your project.

So, does the project use 3-5 or 50 of those DevExpress controls? (by using, I mean DIFFERENT kinds of controls).

If you only used a few, say like their GridView, then you would only need to find a replacement for their gridview control, or simply use the built-in one, and fancy it up with some css, and addtional options. (I would make a user control).

So, you want to determine what the controls used did, how many different controls were used, and then find some controls that have a great look and feel that you like.

Their grid controls are VERY nice, since they have some "really" nice filter options for the header of that grid control.

So, you need to find some control replacements, but how many did the project use will quite much determine scope here.

So, in place of say their tab control, then consider using the jQuery one. As noted, I would wrap say the jQuery.UI tab control into a user control, so then you can just drag + drop in that jQuery.UI "tab" control in place of the devExpress one.

Same goes for the multi-select combo box (dropdown list).

So, either you cobbile together some replacements of your own, or you find some replacemetns, or you buy some more controls from another vendor.

The challenge and issue will of course be that each of their controls has a specific object and event model.

However, that's not really any different then say if you started used sweet-alert, and now want to replace sweet-alert say with some jQuery.UI dialogs.

I would say that the real challenge of replacing their controls is often not so much finding a replacement, but finding something that has a great look and feel. The main huge wonderful bonus of the devExpress controls tends to be their look and feel. In other words, they had someone with REALLY good taste in terms of look and feel.

I mean, for years I used the ajaxtoolkit. (free, open source). it was and still remains a fantastic set of controls. The pop dialog, the tab control, the multi-select combo box, the HTML editor?

They are all great, but their HUGE downside is not the features, but the controls from that free toolkit look like something from the 1980's!!!

The popular jQuery.UI? Same thing, the controls look ugly and something designed by a un-employed rodeo clown living in a trailer park.

There is a HUGE but BEYOND huge reason that bootstap is so popular.

Know the answer?

Why of course bootstrap is popular for ONE big HUGE massive SIMPLE reason:

Bootstrap has a fantastic look + feel. (zero other reasons for bootstrap being popular!!).

If you ever hired a graphic artist to re-work the look and feel of your web site? Guess what? Their resulting work and suggestions will look like the default of bootstrap!!!

So, someone in the print and graphic design industry or someone with VERY good talent and great taste created the bootstrap system. So, when you use bootstrap, then you get fantastic looking results, results that normally would take a full time graphic artist on your staff.

Regardless, we are wondering off topic here.

The main issue you have to determine is how many controls were used from devExpress. Most of their controls do follow a similar object model as the base controls found in asp.net webform controls.

So, for example, jQuery.UI controls has a great set of features (a great set of UI components), but they look way too dated and old fashioned.

The issue you have is not that you want to replace some of the devExpress controls you used, but how much work it would be to replace say a dev-express "gridview" with another different grid control. Every single one of those controls used will not only require you to spend HUGE amounts of time finding a replacement, but I think the LARGER issue is finding something that don't look like it was created by someone living in mom's basement, or by that drunken un-employed rodeo clown that does not belong in our industry.

your issue is not finding some replacement controls, your issue is how much code  and money (time and resources) you have available to replace those controls.

You can no more change a bunch of code in c# to then using say client side JavaScript can then you take some Pascal code, and covert that code to vb.net code.

There no more a replacement for those controls from dev-express then there is deciding tomorrow to re-write some server side code in vb.net to now being client side JavaScript code.

In fact, what I am quite much telling you?

How the computer and IT industry has worked for 50+ years has NOT change one bit, and it not change one bit if you decide to rip out some existing controls and replace them with different controls.

Its possible you are asking for something you never seen, never heard of, and thus are imagining some magic wand here, but those don't exist in our industry either, do they?

As I noted, for quite some time, I used the AjaxToolKit. Turns out that jQuery.UI has near EVERY the same kind of controls available. But, the massive difference is jQuery.UI controls are client side ones, but worse yet, they don't work the same as the AjaxToolKit ones. In other words, there is a nice "tab" control in AjaxToolkit, and there is a nice tab control in jQuery.UI. So, they both are  tab control, but THEY are VAST different in their operations, how you use them, how they work.

However, both the jQuery.UI and the AjaxToolkit tab control?

My gosh, do they look like crap.

At least the jQuery.UI one can be easy bootstrapped styled.

Again, note how we not really now back to a JUST having a control replacement, but one that looks VERY nice and VERY tasteful out of the box, and a control that should take zero efforts on your part to obtain that great look and feel.

Want to know what product has those great looking controls and great look and feel out of the box?

the DevExpress ones!!!

Comment: Many thanks for your reply!
Indeed, when considering the possible solutions, i've completely disregarded the criteria of look'n'feel. Thanks again for pointing this out! The more i think about, the more it seems to make sense to simply migrate controls one-by-one from DevExpress Bootstrap (old, in maintenance mode, tied down to .NET Core 2.0) towards DevExpress ASP.NET Core (new, updated, offering support for .NET Core 6.0 and beyond). Will drill into the code in the following days in order to see how many changes would be needed.